# validar formulario con jquery-validate en ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-validate

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema, he realizado una función guardar con **PHP** y **Codeigniter**, utilizando **AJAX** también.. todo funciona bien, pero resulta que quiero validar mi formulario usando *jquery-validate* antes de realizar la petición **AJAX**, para eso ya tengo mis reglas de validación y mi código es el siguiente:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
 
    $("#form_create").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {
                if(response.success === true) {
                    $(".messages").html('<div class="alert bg-blue alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                      '<strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                    '</div>').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');

                    $("#form_create")[0].reset();
            
                } else {
                    
                    $(".messages").html('<div class="alert bg-red alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                    '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                    '</div>');
                }
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    });

});
```

El código funciona bien.. y guarda.. ahora mi duda es donde agregar el siguiente código con mis reglas de validación:

```html
$('#form_create').validate({

            highlight: function (input) {
                $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (input) {
                $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más fácil es incluir el submit en la validación, en lugar de hacer lo contrario.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_create').validate({
        ...     
        submitHandler : function(_form)
          {
            var form = $(_form);
            $.ajax({
               // tu código ajax
            })
            return false;
          }
        ...
    });    
});
```

Los puntos suspensivos indican tus validaciones ya creadas.

Comment: lo probare y te comento gracias

Comment: gracias era lo que me faltaba.. :)